# Tensorflow-GPU not using GPU with CUDA,CUDNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I want to use Tensorflow on GPU. So I install all the needed tool and installed as below-

1. CUDA-11.2
2. CUDNN-11.1
3. Anaconda-2020.11
4. Tensorflow-GPU-2.3.0
   [image]

I tested that my cuda,cudnn is working using deviseQuery example.
But Tensorflow not used GPU. Then i find that version compatibility issue is possible so i innstalled CudaToolkit,cudnn using conda environment checking with version compatibility on Tensorflow website which is given below.

1. CUDA-10.2.89
2. CUDNN-7.6.5
3. Tensorflow-GPU-2.3.0

[image]
[image]
[image]

But after this try Tensorflow-GPU not used GPU,yet. so what i am doing now? Any steps or suggestion require.

Comment: The installation engine has a problem for tensorflow-gpu 2.3 in Anaconda on Windows 10. Workaround is to explicitly specify the correct tensorflow build: `conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.3 tensorflow=2.3=mkl_py38h1fcfbd6_0`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks TFer2! Your comment should be marked as solution. I had the same issue, your solution worked for me with additionally installing `cudatoolkit=10.1` (not 10.2).

Comment: @BenJW `cudatoolkit` should be automatically installed by the command like for TF 2.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The installation engine has a problem for `tensorflow-gpu 2.3` in Anaconda on Windows 10.

Workaround is to explicitly specify the correct tensorflow build:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.3 tensorflow=2.3=mkl_py38h1fcfbd6_0
```

Comment: Getting a `PackagesNotFoundError:` from your suggestion..

Comment: `conda search "tensorflow-gpu"` only shows versions up to `2.2.0`, the `2.3.0` you suggest is not present. On the other hand, `conda search "tensorflow"` shows some `2.3.0` versions, but none of them are tagged with `mkl_py38h1fcfbd6_0`.

Comment: Ahhh, never mind. I was running the `install` and `search` commands from a WSL terminal instead of the Windows one. My GPU now works properly on Windows! :)

Comment: Worked for me as well, I also have Ge Force 1650

Comment: Hello! I am having a similar problem, can you please have a look at it? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384700/cuda-drivers-being-not-identified-by-tensorflow