# Installed tensorflow but can't detect GTX 1650 Super

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using Win 10 Pro 64bit. I have already:

- installed latest graphics card drivers for GTX 1650 SUPER (w/ CUDA 11.2.109 driver)
- installed CUDA drivers
- installed Anaconda and activated environment
- installed Python 3.8.0
- installed Tensorflow 2.3.0
- installed cudatoolkit 10.2.89, (then 11.0.221 later)
- installed cudnn 7.6.5.32 to relevant folders
- Checked PATH entries

nvidia-smi shows the card.

Yet,
Python
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
*returns* tf.Tensor(1348.6893, shape=(), dtype=float32)

tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
*returns* []

tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
*returns* False

What am I missing?

I have this working on my friends' 980ti seemingly with the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...

installed Python 3.8.0 &
installed Pillow (Don't know why. Thought I installed it last time I guess.)
installed "tensorflow-gpu=2.3 tensorflow=2.3=mkl_py38h1fcfbd6_0" as recommended at [Tensorflow-GPU not using GPU with CUDA,CUDNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65381073/tensorflow-gpu-not-using-gpu-with-cuda-cudnn)

and it worked.